# if statement is not doing anithing when option is selected JS

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have a script that creates options in select and another script that should write `test` in console when I'm choosing `electro` option. But It's not working.

scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    function addOption() {
      var optionArr = ['-', 'eletro', 'auto'];
      var select = document.getElementsByName('butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling')[0];
      for(var i=0; i<optionArr.length; i++){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.text = optionArr[i];
        opt.value = optionArr[i];
        select.add(opt);
      }
    }

    addOption();
  });
  
  
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  let autofilling = document.getElementsByName('butterbean_stm_car_manager_setting_autofilling').value;
  if(autofilling == 'eletro'){
   console.log('test'); 
  };
</script>
```

THERE IS NO CONSOLE ERRORS

Comment: you read the value on page rendering. It is not going to keep updating. You need an event listener

Comment: Try console.log(autofilling) before the if statement and see what that outputs

Comment: @epascarello What should I do with code?